# How to get the form validation status in "react-validation", when submitting the form?

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation

I'm trying to use [react-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation) for simple form validation in React. I understood how to validate the fields according to my needs, but what i do not understand, is how to get the "status" of the form, when the user tries to submit the it.

The documentation says that the Form component provides 4 public methods:
validate(name), validateAll(), showError(component [,error]), hideError(component)

From what i understand, these methods are accessible by a ref to the Form component:

```
<Form ref={c => { this.form = c }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

When i console log this.form in my submit handler, i do get an object with the above mentioned methods, but when i call one of them, like validateAll(), it returns undefined. I do not understand why.

Can someone help me with this specific plugin, or perhaps recommend a different **simple** alternative? I need to perform very basic validation(but can't use HTML built in one), and do not need something fancy like react-form or redux-form(i do not even use Redux in this project)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked it in sandbox, please review it,

[image: Edit x36o24lpwo]

and I can tall you that it DOES work in this way. When you call `this.form.validateAll()` it returns `undefined` BUT it executes all validation functions and appends to form error messages defined in that functions. So may be it is even unnecessary `validateAll` to return smth

The solution I have found to provide `state.isValid`. Set `isValid = true` on form change

```
handleChange() {
  this.setState({ isValid: true });
}
```

and in each validator set `state.isValid = false` if validation is not pass

Comment: I see, but i still don't understand how u could prevent the form from being submitted, if the form state is invalid? I mean, i did find a "solution", by just using their Button component, which goes disabled when the form is invalid. But i don't know how i could do it programatically, within the handleSubmit function. I didn't see u made any conditionals there.

Comment: Please review a sandbox, I have modifyed it. Looks little intricately, but this validation library really not allows to perform such simple check. Or maybe somebody else will advice us smth better.